# Does MySQL truncate parameters in stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, procedure

So I am aware that in SQL Server if some procedure is expecting a varchar(5) and it receives '123456', this will automatically truncated to '12345'. Does this happen in MySQL too?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: It should since the size is specified as 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your `sql_mode` setting.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode

Comment: So you mean, based on `sql_mode` setting the truncation will not happen? That's a strange feature.

Comment: @Rahul Some `sql_mode` settings are strict and would throw an error rather than silently truncating the content. If you're working with sensitive data this can be important - you'd really rather not insert the wrong bank balance into someone's account because of a type mismatch.

Comment: That's what exactly I mean, it should always restrict. taking your bank example ... If it's a integrity constraint that withdrawal amount <= 5 digit and by sql_mode if it's allows 6 digit then where are we?

Comment: Anyways, +1 nice answer. Didn't knew it till date ... LOL.